# What is a good collaboration website for developers?

Tags: development-environment

We have a number of developers located around the world which we need to collaborate with.

Our functionality required is:

1. Some sort of white board, which multiple users can view, and update.
2. A private wiki.
3. A ticket system for managing workload.
4. A source control system would be nice, but not required.

Ideally this would already be hosted somewhere (and free), alternatively if any software 
can do this, which is also not expensive, that would be fine.

Ideally all this functionality would run over standard http.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like [Assembla](http://www.assembla.com), among others it offers:
  - SVN
  - Trac
  - MessageBoard
  - Wiki
and some more features. Also you get 200MB free space for every project...

Comment: They have also begun offering Git and Mercurial.

Answer (score 3):

Base Camp may provide some of what you need: http://www.basecamphq.com/

Answer (score 1):

[Slicehost](http://www.slicehost.com/) + [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) + [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/)/[Mercurial](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/wiki/)/[Git](http://git.or.cz/)/[Bazaar](http://bazaar-vcs.org/).

Unfortunately, I don't know of any open source whiteboards :(

The advantage of configuring your own machine is that you can configure whatever you want. It would be a real shame if your development team decided that bzr was the way they wanted to go, but you're hosted project management app didn't support it very well.

Answer (score 0):

#### [GitHub](https://github.com/)

The free plan is for open source but it can be used for private projects too. Includes:

- Wiki
- Issue tracker
- Source control